# MS Access: Output and format a file with Single Space Lines in MS Word

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, output, spacing

I have a report from Ms Access, which I have the Row space formatting in Print Preview set to 0". You can find it under Page setup or columns. However when it outputs the file in MS Word there appears to be additional spacing which I cannot remove from adjusting the row space in Ms Access and has to be manually changed in another word processor. Could someone write an example macro VBA code which will do this?

Here is some sample code if it may be added to to format in single space for MS Word:

```
    'newsletter
  DoCmd.OpenForm "Reports Menu", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal
  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  Forms("Reports Menu").Date.SetFocus
    DoCmd.OpenReport ("ContributorList"), acViewPreview
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    stDocName = "ContributorList"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, stDocName, acFormatRTF
  MsgBox "A copy of project contributors was made in MS Word file..."
```

The following code is a snippet from a reference at 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193108.aspx

I am curious if anyone thinks this can be used to make a single space document?

```
 With Selection.ParagraphFormat 
     .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceAtLeast 
     .LineSpacing = 24 
    End With
```

Comment: When you open a new Word document does it default to the desired line spacing settings?

Comment: I am not sure. I need it to do this for another individual too.

Comment: `LineSpacing` is a Word property, so in order to interact with it in Access you will need to create an instance of the Word Application first, output your file, then change the spacing with the Word Application object that you created. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821081.aspx